# How to mock ApplicationContext context = getContext(); of HttpSecurity to prevent nullPointer Exception in below testcase

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, mockito, junit5

Upgraded springboot version from 2.5.6 to 2.6.3

After upgrading testcase written for configuration class is throwing nullpointerException.

HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests() throwing NullPointerException in configure() method.

In latest version implementation of ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer(ApplicationContext context) has been changed and its trying to fetch getBeanNamesForType from ApplicationContext which is resulting in NullpointerException( getContext method called in HttpSecurity-> authorizeRequests returns null in both old and latest version)

TESTCASE

```
    @Mock
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder amb;
    @Mock
    ObjectPostProcessor<Object> opp;
    @Mock
    Map<Class<? extends Object>, Object> sharedObjects;


    @Test
    public void configureTrue() throws Exception{
        HttpSecurity http=new HttpSecurity(opp, amb, sharedObjects);
        SecurityConfig securityConfig=new SecurityConfig();
        securityConfig.requireHttps=true;
        securityConfig.managementSecurityEnabled=true;
        securityConfig.configure(http); //calls conigure method of configuration class(Failing here)
        securityConfig.requireHttps=false;
        securityConfig.managementSecurityEnabled=false;
        assertNotNull(http);
    }
```

**App.java(Main method class which has SecurityConfig.class)**

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Value("${management.security.enabled}")
        protected boolean managementSecurityEnabled;

        @Value("${security.require_ssl}")
        protected boolean requireHttps;

        public boolean isManagementSecurityEnabled() {
            return managementSecurityEnabled;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();


            if (isManagementSecurityEnabled()) {

// authorizeRequests() is the one throwing nullpointerException
http.antMatcher("/management/admin/v1/met/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                        .hasRole("ACTUATOR").and().httpBasic();

            }
        }
    }
```

**HttpSecurity.class**

```
    public ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry authorizeRequests()
                throws Exception {
            ApplicationContext context = getContext(); //getting null for context
            return getOrApply(new ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<>(context)).getRegistry();
        }
```

**ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer**

```
/**
     * Creates a new instance
     * @see HttpSecurity#authorizeRequests()
     */
    public ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer(ApplicationContext context) {

//Getting failed here(NullPointer Exception) since we are getting context as null
        String[] grantedAuthorityDefaultsBeanNames = context.getBeanNamesForType(GrantedAuthorityDefaults.class); 
        if (grantedAuthorityDefaultsBeanNames.length == 1) {
            GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults = context.getBean(grantedAuthorityDefaultsBeanNames[0],
                    GrantedAuthorityDefaults.class);
            this.rolePrefix = grantedAuthorityDefaults.getRolePrefix();
        }
        else {
            this.rolePrefix = "ROLE_";
        }
        this.REGISTRY = new ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry(context);
    }
```

Comment: same question as this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71322261/nullpointerexception-at-org-springframework-security-config-annotation-web-confi

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
private HashMap<Class<?>, Object> getSharedObjets(){
    HashMap map = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();
    GenericApplicationContext context= new GenericApplicationContext();
    context.refresh();
    map.put(ApplicationContext.class, context);
    return map;
}
```